# Is there an Open Source pastebin?

Tags: open-source, sharing, pastebin

Frequently I write wiki pages or set up configuration files that I need to share with other developers. Are there any pastebin clones out there that you can install in your own network and if not? how do you manage code snippets or configurations you wish to share with other developers in your company where source control may be overkill?

Comment: Better suited to http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: You can try NoPaste at https://nopaste.ml
It's similar to Pastebin, except it works with no database, and no back-end code, which is great for the privacy of your data

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is stikked. A simple and powerfull open-source pastebin, using PHP.

You can check it at "stikked.com" and you can download the source from http://code.google.com/p/stikked.

There's a bugfixed/improved version: https://github.com/claudehohl/Stikked

Comment: stikked.com now redirects to a personal blog; the code is still available, though.

Comment: There's a Windows client for Stikked available at http://stikkpop.wirehive.net/

Answer (score 5):

There's also "haste server" (https://github.com/seejohnrun/haste-server), which has a public  version hosted at hastebin.com that you can try out.

Comment: Also mentionable: It's written in node (so nothing for shared hosts/simple webhosts)

Answer (score 2):

Try securePaste, it's a good pastebin-like : https://bitbucket.org/Popoliito/securepaste

Answer (score 1):

Also try trashbin https://github.com/igorw/trashbin

Answer (score -1):

Here you can find an example with php-pastebin-v3 :

http://www.skytek.fr