# Software/Web Application for Sharing Code Snippets Internally

Tags: code-snippets

Does anyone know of a web app and/or software that can be installed and run locally to share code snippets?

We would like to encourage code reuse and re-factoring within our organization but using sites like http://snippets.dzone.com/ or http://pastebin.com/ wouldn't work very well in this scenario because we want to keep this private. Visual Studio has support for code snippets but that's geared more towards individual developers and not for group sharing.

Does anyone have any suggestions for an app/tool that might accomplish this goal?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Open Source PasteBin ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909251/open-source-pastebin)

Answer (score 1):

you can use http://codetidy.com/ or https://gist.github.com/